# Delete Even Numbers From A Linked List C++

Tags: c++, list, linked-list

I can't seem to understand what am I missing, I've spent hours and hours looking at this and everything I tried doesn't work.

My thought process to check if the second node of the list is even, if it is then to link the first and third node and delete the second but it doesn't work... I've been stuck at this for a week.

```
void delete_even()
{
   nod *aux;
   if (head == NULL)
   {
      cout << "List doesn't exist!";
   }
   else
   {
      nod *curent;
      current = head;
      while (curent)
      {
         if (curent->next->info % 2 == 0)
         {
            curent = curent->next->next;
            curent->next = aux;
            delete aux;
            break;
         }
         else
         {
            curent = curent->next;
         }
      } 
   }
}
```

I don't know what else to do.

Comment: [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: I would advise to properly indent your code. It will help you to analyse your code.

Comment: when you are comparing `head == NULL` where is head defined?

Comment: This task should take about a dozen lines of code, if one is skilled with pointers. This question's code/phrasing very likely came from one of many countless coding challenge/puzzle websites. They take advantage of people who want to learn C++ by offering arcane coding puzzles, promising that you don't need to study and learn C++ with a good textbook, just do one puzzle after another. Everyone eventually realizes that these arcane coding puzzles are a waste of time, and there's nothing to be learned from them. But only after wasting a lot of time doing them. And there's nothing to show for it.

Comment: Split up the task to make multiple simpler jobs that you can do more easily. Write a function that removes a node. Test the crap out of it to ensure that it works. Then call it on even-number-storing nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this code.

Your use of `curent->next` invokes *undefined behavior* when `curent` is pointing at the last node in the list, since `next` will be `NULL` in that case.  It is are causing you to skip the 1st node in the list.

You never assign `aux` to point at anything, so calling `delete` on `aux` is also *undefined behavior*.

Even if `aux` were pointing at a valid node, you are assigning `aux` to `curent->next` right before deleting the node that `aux` is pointing at, thus leaving `curent->next` pointing at invalid memory, which is also *undefined behavior*.

If you did manage to remove a node from the list, you are breaking the loop immediately afterwards, so you would be removing only one even number from the list, not removing all even numbers, as your title suggests you want to do.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
void delete_even()
{
   if (!head)
      cout << "List is empty!";
   else
   {
      nod *curent = head, *prev = NULL;
      while (curent)
      {
         nod *next = curent->next;
         if (curent->info % 2 == 0)
         {
            if (prev)
               prev->next = next;
            else
               head = next;
            delete curent;
         }
         else
         {
            prev = curent;
         }
         curent = next;
      }
   }
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
void delete_even()
{
   if (!head)
      cout << "List is empty!";
   else
   {
      nod *curent = head;
      nod **prev = &head;
      while (curent)
      {
         if (curent->info % 2 == 0)
         {
            *prev = curent->next;
            delete curent;
         }
         else
         {
            prev = &(curent->next);
         }
         curent = *prev;
      }
   }
}
```